# NuGet package isn't available to GitHub Actions for several hours after granting permissions

Tags: github-actions

After I have published a new NuGet package and set the access for GitHub Actions, it takes several hours for it to take affect.  Until then, my GitHub Actions that are trying to use the NuGet package get back 403 Forbidden errors.  Without taking any other steps, the action will start succeeding in a few hours.